# Extending a list in one module from another -- without any lines in the old module?

Tags: python, list, module, extend, maya

I'm trying to think of ways to extend a list variable in one python file (original.py) from a completely different one (addition.py).

The catch is that I can't add any lines to the original.py file.

Is this remotely possible? I'd like to do it with the stock Python libs rather than adding any batch files, etc. as a second process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the list in `original.py` is defined as a module level variable you can access it from outside to append, remove, sort etc.

```
# original.py

original_list = [1,2,3]
```

and

```
# addition.py

import original
original.original_list.append(4)

print original.original_list
#  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```